# Plot list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, vector, plot

I'm trying to plot a list of points in R.
My structure is like this:

```
myList
|_p1=(x1,y2)
|_p2=(x2,y2)
.
.
.
|_pn=(xn,yn)
```

I get this list with the command:

`myList<-lapply(seq_len(50),function(i) runif(2,-50,50));`

So, I will get 50 points with ramdom values between -50 and 50.

Now, I want to plot this points (without for, it is slow). I've tried with `lapply` function but maybe I don't know how to use correctly. This lines doesn't work correctly:

```
plot(NA,xlim=c(-50,50),ylim=c(-50,50))
lapply(myList,points)
```

I'm just a beginner with R and I don't dominate it... How can I do it with `lapply` if is possible? How `lapply` works?

Thanks!

Comment: you should save the points as a data.frame and not as a list.

Comment: `plot(do.call(rbind, myList))`

Comment: Using lists is a requeriment of my problem :(

Comment: Thanks for your response, baptiste. Your code is not the same as `plot(rbind(myList))`? How `do.call` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you should look at `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(x=runif(50,-50,50),y=runif(50,-50,50))
```

Nevertheless, if you have a list due to other requirements you can use

```
plot(t(as.data.frame(myList)))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I need more experience to dominate dataframes.